# Couchbase DCP Client 0.10.0 fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, couchbase

I am working on a DCP client connector with following versions.

- DCP Client version `0.10.0`
- Java Client version `2.4.6`
- Core IO version `1.4.6`
- Rx Java version `1.2.7` (this is automatically
  pulled)

Whenever I run my application, I am getting following exception. I tried altering the versions of these libraries, but no luck yet. Appreciate if someone could help.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.core.config.NodeInfo.hostname()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
    at com.couchbase.client.dcp.conductor.HttpStreamingConfigProvider$1.onNext(HttpStreamingConfigProvider.java:90) ~[dcp-client-0.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.dcp.conductor.HttpStreamingConfigProvider$1.onNext(HttpStreamingConfigProvider.java:74) ~[dcp-client-0.10.0.jar:?]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:134) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:135) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(SubjectSubscriptionManager.java:253) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject.onNext(BehaviorSubject.java:160) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:91) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at rx.subjects.SerializedSubject.onNext(SerializedSubject.java:67) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
    at com.couchbase.client.dcp.transport.netty.ConfigHandler.decodeChunk(ConfigHandler.java:96) ~[dcp-client-0.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.dcp.transport.netty.ConfigHandler.channelRead0(ConfigHandler.java:76) ~[dcp-client-0.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.dcp.transport.netty.ConfigHandler.channelRead0(ConfigHandler.java:38) ~[dcp-client-0.10.0.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:625) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:560) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:477) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:439) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) ~[core-io-1.4.6.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in one line: use `dcp-client` version `0.10.0` with `core-io` version `1.4.4` and this problem will be gone.

I got the answer from Couchbase folks; the entire discussion is here https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-dcp-client-0-10-0-fails-with-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror/13227.

The class `NodeInfo` has been changed in latest version of `core-io` (v`1.4.6`); the method `NodeInfo.hostName()` returns a new class called `NetworkAddress`. In prior versions it was returning `InetAddress`. For some reason Couchbase folks did not update `dcp-client` version `0.10.0` to use the newer APIs. As per the discussion in above link, they will be releasing that soon.